# How to fix 'Not acceptable format: json' message

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have created a new entity `panel_caption_label` in my project drupal and activated API route for GET this entity.

My `rest.resource.entity.panel_caption_label.yml` config file ⤵️

```yaml
uuid: da80fe4a-c7ec-49b2-94eb-9afaa69fe399
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - atlantic
    - serialization
    - user
id: entity.panel_caption_label
plugin_id: 'entity:panel_caption_label'
granularity: resource
configuration:
  methods:
    - GET
    - POST
    - DELETE
    - PATCH
  formats:
    - json
  authentication:
    - cookie
```

But when I try to do a `GET http://localhost:950/api/panel-caption-label/panel_caption_label?_format=json`

I get this message ⤵️

```json
{
    "message": "Not acceptable format: json"
}
```

I have tried to export config and import manually, but nothing work...

How to fix it ?

Thank a lot !

Comment: Sorry, can't see images

Comment: @DDS I have change the image, you see now ?

Comment: You shouid NOT post (code as) images if you want that also people behind aggressive firewalls gets your messages. You should copy-paste (or re-type) it in a code (or quote) block instead

Comment: @DDS This is not a code but a screen of my configuration for this entity in my drupal application.

Comment: I have changed the screen for config file